# JavaScript function to find the first result in an array

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a functional way to find the first result in an array.

```
let result;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result = functionThatCalulatesResult(array[i]);
  if (result) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Is the imperative way.

```
const item = array.find(i => functionThatCalulatesResult(i));
```

But now I have to calculate the result again.

```
const result = array.reduce(
  (result, item) => result ? result : functionThatCalulatesResult(i), 
  undefined
);
```

But the reduce keeps going over all the items that don't need to be iterated.

I am looking for something like

```
const result = firstResult(array, i => functionThatCalulatesResult(i));
```

That returns the first truthy result for the function without iterating the items past the first result.

Most efficient thing I can think of is

```
const firstResult = (array, func) => {
  let result;
  array.some(i => result = func(i));
  return result;
}
```

But it is not purely functional with the mutating of result.

Edit:

For people asking what is in the array I am trying to find the most efficient way of finding the parameter that returns a sort direction in this function.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-syhjq4

I was using a reduce but have switched to a some with a mutation as the sort function mutates the array anyway.

Comment: It's not clear what is inside `array` or what `functionThatClaculatesResult` is returning. You are on the right path with `Array.find` though.

Comment: As a tangent, your code `const item = array.find(i => functionThatCalulatesResult(i));` could be rewritten as: `const item = array.find(functionThatCalulatesResult);` since the Array methods pass the array element as the first argument anyway.

Comment: `const item = array[array.findIndex(functionThatCalculatesResult)];`?

Comment: *:That returns the first truthy result for the function without iterating the items past the first result."* `some()`

Comment: Wait why do you have to "calculate the result again"? The `.find()` method returns the item that first satisfies the predicate, not a boolean.

Comment: @Pointy I think he means that he has to redo the function he uses in find, which in his case does most likely not return a boolean, but a truthy value that he needs later on

Comment: Why do you need `array.reduce` rather than just `functionThatCalulatesResult()` on the result of `find()`?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here? It sounds like you're trying to reproduce `Array.prototype.find()`, which already returns the first item it finds, or `null` if it can't find anything.

Comment: In regards about `some()` *"But it is not purely functional with the mutating of result."* `some()` does not mutate, if there's any mutation going on it's those fictional functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, perhaps you could achieve what you need by first reducing the `array` of values to a `Set`.

This would mean the subsequent `find()` as shown below only operates on unique values (this avoiding redundant iterations and reprocessing of `functionThatCalulatesResult()` on duplicate array items):

```js
// Mock functionThatCalulatesResult() to illustrate this answers
// idea. The function returns truthy when value 5 encountered
function functionThatCalulatesResult(i) {
  console.log('visiting:', i )      
  if(i === 5) {
    return true;
  }  
}

var array = [1,2,3,1,3,1,5,6];

// Reducing array to unique set of values avoid reprocessing of 
// functionThatCalulatesResult() on duplicate values that don't 
// return truthy
var result = Array.from(new Set(array)).find(functionThatCalulatesResult);

console.log('result', result)
```

Comment: I am looking to improve efficiency, running up a new array is about the most inefficient way possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because as far as I know you can't do this efficient with the standard "functional" methods.

Honestly, the best way, is to encapsulate your imperative loop in a function.
I know this might not be the most satisfying answer, but personally I found that your code actually becomes a lot cleaner when you use imperative code sometimes:

```
let map_find = (array, map_fn) => {
  for (let item of array) {
    let result = map_fn(array[i]);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }
}

// use map_find like it is super functional
const item = map_find(array, i => functionThatCalulatesResult(i));
```

(Also `for (... of ...)` still looks a lot better than a for-loop ;) )